# Removing objectsClasses and attributeTypes from ldap using ObjectID only

Tags: ldap, opendj

I have been trying to remove objectsClasses, and attributeTypes from a local openDJ instance via a script. The goal is to create a set of scripts to destroy and then recreate the server, so that when changes occur each developer/instance can simply have the scripts ran and be ready to go. I have been successful at removing objests and attributes using the full definition, but when I try to use the ObjectID it is unable to find the objects/attributes.
`"Entry cn=schema cannot be modified because the attempt to update objectClasses would have removed one or more values from the attribute that were not present: (1.1.2.2.2) "`

Working ldif:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
delete: objectClasses
objectclasses: ( 1.1.2.2.2 NAME 'tstPerson'
            DESC 'Person object'
            SUP inetOrgPerson
            STRUCTURAL
            MUST ( name )
            MAY ( unit ) 
             ) 

dn: cn=schema
changetype:modify
delete:attributeTypes
attributeTypes: (2.16.3.1.1
   NAME 'unit'
   DESC 'identifies the unit or units a person has been assigned'
   EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
   SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
   SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
```

Shortened Non working:

```
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
delete: objectClasses
objectclasses: ( 1.1.2.2.2 ) 

dn: cn=schema
changetype:modify
delete:attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 2.16.3.1.1 )
```

The question is, in order to delete an objectClass or attribute, does the full definition of the objectClass or attribute need to be provided, or is there a way to specifically identify the objectClass or attribute with a name or OID?

Comment: Try it without the brackets. Strange thing to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked and it works with just the OID and the name.

```
$ ldapmodify -D cn=directory\ manager -w secret12 -p 1389
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
delete: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: (2.16.3.1.1 NAME 'unit')

Processing MODIFY request for cn=schema
MODIFY operation successful for DN cn=schema
```

I need to verify why just the OID is not sufficient, but this should help you moving forward

Comment: You shouldn't need both the name and the OID. What happened when you tried the OID without the parentheses?

Comment: If there are no parentheses, OpenDJ will reject the value as not compliant with an attributeTypeDescription.

BTW, this only works with the development version of OpenDJ (coming 3.0 release). We moved using the objectIdentifierFirstComponentMatch rule for schema recently.